# What is the difference between software rendering vs. gpu rendering

Tags: canvas, gpu, rendering

I have no idea with the difference between rendering 2D or 3D object in canvas with software/GPU rendering.
Can anyone help me out with the difference?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Software rendering means that the rendering calculations are done on the CPU -- the main general-purpose processor in your computer.

Hardware / GPU rendering means that the rendering calculations are done on the GPU -- a specialized microchip that some computers have that is optimized for doing 3D math and other calculations very quickly.

CPUs will break up complex math operations into several smaller pieces.  Each piece takes a fixed amount of time for the CPU to calculate, so the more pieces, the longer the operation takes.  Sometimes this can be very inefficient.

A GPU is designed to handle the complex sort of math operations needed for graphics rendering without being broken up into so many pieces.  Breaking it up into fewer pieces means that it can accomplish the same math in fewer steps, and graphics are rendered more quickly as a result.